# How to turn off automatic slash adding inside URL in angular router

Tags: angular

Is it possible to turn off the angular behavior to add a slash in the middle of my URL? The app has also some old PHP parts that need to get reworked, so I need the exact URL like shown below.

I access this ULR

http://localhost/ui/index.php?session_id=SOMEID

and angular add a slash after the .php

http://localhost/ui/index.php/?session_id=SOMEID

Answer (score 0):

How about adding angular query params to the route?

If you use routerLink:

```
[routerLink]="['/index.php']" [queryParams]="{session_id: SOMEID}"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.The problem is that after the slash was added the user cant refresh or even bookmark the page. The session id comes from outside the angular part and clearly I handle it inside angular. I use a settings service to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1) Update your web server so that index.php is your default and handles all routes under UI.  Then your urls will look like `http://localhost/ui` and `http://localhost/ui/path/to/angular/route`

2) Use HashLocationStrategy.  Pass the options `{ useHash: true }` to your call to RouterModule.forRoot:

```
  RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
```

Now urls will look like this: `http://localhost/ui/index.php#/`.

***EDIT***

I'm not sure how adding the query parameter with the session id is part of the problem.  Angular routing works as a single page app, once you're in it, it doesn't go back to the server when you change routes.  If you link to other parts of your site and need to put the session id in there you'll have to store it when your app loads and add it to the links you have in your angular app.  Are there any other issues you could have problems with?